# Apache Ignite. WeightedRandomLoadBalancingSpi. Как сделать так, чтобы на узел с большим весом уходило большее количество заданий?

Tags: apache

Apache Ignite. Пробую использовать в качестве loadBalancingSpi WeightedRandomLoadBalancingSpi. У одного узла задаю вес 10, у другого - 100. У узла с весом 10 более слабая конфигурация. Логи показывают, что количество задач уходит на оба узла одинаковое.

Как сделать так, чтобы на узел с большим весом уходило большее количество заданий?

Конфиг 1

```
    <property name="loadBalancingSpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.loadbalancing.weightedrandom.WeightedRandomLoadBalancingSpi">
          <property name="useWeights" value="true"/>
          <property name="nodeWeight" value="10"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

Конфиг 2

```
    <property name="loadBalancingSpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.loadbalancing.weightedrandom.WeightedRandomLoadBalancingSpi">
          <property name="useWeights" value="true"/>
          <property name="nodeWeight" value="100"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как указано в javadoc [WeightedRandomLoadBalancingSpi](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/loadbalancing/weightedrandom/WeightedRandomLoadBalancingSpi.html), можно использовать [ComputeTaskSplitAdapter](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/compute/ComputeTaskSplitAdapter.html) или же обычный [ComputeTask](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/compute/ComputeTask.html) с внедренной зависимостью

```
@LoadBalancerResource
ComputeLoadBalancer balancer;
```

которую можно использовать в методе [map](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/compute/ComputeTask.html#map-java.util.List-T-).

```
 public Map<? extends ComputeJob, ClusterNode> map(List<ClusterNode> subgrid, String arg) throws IgniteCheckedException {
     Map<MyFooBarJob, ClusterNode> jobs = new HashMap<>();
     jobs.put(new MyFooBarJob(arg), balancer.getBalancedNode());
     return jobs;
 }
```